# What plant is it? Why its leaves look weak now than the first time I bought it?

Tags: identification, plant-care

[image]

Did I underwater it. Is it because the sunlight or just needs fertilizer? It’s been a week. I just move it outside this morning though. It’s not direct sun and I fertilized it with mono potassium phosphate this morning also

UPDATE
I THOUGHT I WATER IT ENOUGH
BUT I CHECKED WITH THE SOIL tester is turns out dry for many days. first I might watch the soil PH moist, for the sun its just medium light as the tester shows, but I don’t know do I have to move it to brighter place? I think I might just watch the moist level first and yep not gonna fertilize it until next week or as some people say next month? okay, I got you.

Comment: Isn't this your water bamboo? Foliage plants need nitrogen, not much potassium for roots, and little phosphorous for the flowers and fruit they don't make.

Comment: @YosefBaskin okay, I got you, I also fertilize it with some nitrogen actually, and other stuff come as one package. but i will keep in mind about it. you mean potassium is for roots? phosphorous for flowers and fruits?

Comment: Yes, they are. So a 'balanced' fertilizer (say 10-10-10) is okay in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an [Equisetum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equisetum) of some kind, possibly *E. hyemale*. Equisetums are a very ancient genus of green plants that reproduce by spores rather than by flowers, and are commonly found in moist environments. In gardens, *E. hyemale* is usually considered a weed. I would stop fertilizing it for a while, then start again with a very weak fertilizer in a month or two, after the leaves have recovered. Remember to keep the soil moist, but not water-logged.

Comment: And AFAIK I know, equisetum have very very long roots (and possibly some large populations are just one single plant. And yeah, they may be considered pests: they are a family far from flowering plants, so most weedkillers have no effect on them: so careful (but I like them on wild, usually on "secret spot" few people go)

Comment: is the indirect light okay? outside with some shade/roof over? i think i underwater it, since knowing the pot don’t come with water escapes. also do you mean Equisetum hyemale
which means this plant can have flower someday? like on the link you gave me show some orange honey like on top of the stem.

Comment: I've seen some Equisetum species in full sun, but in a lot of water. Less sun should equal less water needed. If the plants continue to look unhealthy after a few weeks, move into more sun. Equisetums do produce a fruiting body of a sort, but it is not a flower - they reproduce only by spores.